# How do i go about developing a facial identification software that identify different users and show their name from an image database using C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to develop a facial recognition software that holds a database of different images and uses the camera to identify each person and shows their name on screen. I'm more familiar with using C++ and I assume python might be the best language to get the job done but I want to know how I can go about it with C++. what algorithm do I have to use and a break down of how I can do it. thank you (:

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949494/how-to-do-face-recognition-using-opencv https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574623/c-face-detection-recognition-implementations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905121/robust-face-detection-in-c-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. OpenCV must be installed on the local machine.
2. Paths to the classifier XML files must be given before the execution of the program. These XML files can be found in the OpenCV directory “opencv/data/haarcascades”.
3. Use 0 in capture.open(0) to play webcam feed.
4. For detection in a local video provide the path to the video.(capture.open(“path_to_video”)).

[You can get in-depth knowledge here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html)

[Tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)